# Oracle row level security setup?

Tags: oracle, row-level-security

How can I configure a table such that a user can modify a row "owned" by that user, but not modify rows "owned" by other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a row-level security policy with a `statement_type` limited to `update` (or more likely `update` and `delete`, and maybe `insert` too). See the [DMBS_RLS.ADD_POLICY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_rls.htm#BABFDECH) docs for details.

Dummy scenario: a list of tasks, only task owners can modify their task.

```
create table owners(owner_id int primary key
                  , owner_name varchar2(10));
create table tasks(task_id int primary key
                 , owner_id int
                 , description varchar2(20)
                 , completion number);

insert into owners(owner_id, owner_name) values (1, 'Mat');
insert into owners(owner_id, owner_name) values (2, 'Mark');
insert into tasks(task_id, owner_id, description, completion)
       values (100, 1, 'Task for Mat', 0);
insert into tasks(task_id, owner_id, description, completion)
       values (200, 2, 'Task for Mark', 0);
commit;
```

The policy function:

```
create or replace 
function tasks_update_policy(schema varchar2, tab varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  owner_id  number;
begin
  select owner_id into owner_id 
    from owners
    where lower(owner_name) = lower(sys_context('userenv','session_user'));
  return 'owner_id = ' || owner_id;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return '1=2';  -- deny unregistered users
end;
```

Implementing the policy:

```
begin
  dbms_rls.add_policy(object_schema => 'MAT'
        , object_name => 'TASKS'
        , policy_name => 'Tasks_update_policy'
        , policy_function => 'tasks_update_policy'
        , statement_types => 'update,delete,insert'   -- policy restriction
        , update_check => true);
end;
/
```

When logged in as myself:

```
SQL> select * from mat.tasks;

   TASK_ID   OWNER_ID DESCRIPTION      COMPLETION
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
       100      1 Task for Mat          0
       200      2 Task for Mark         0

SQL> update mat.tasks set completion = 20 where task_id = 100 ;

1 row updated.

SQL> update mat.tasks set completion = 20 where task_id = 200 ;

0 rows updated.
```

When connected as 'Mark':

```
SQL> insert into mat.tasks values (101, 1, 'More work for Mat', 0);
insert into mat.tasks values (101, 1, 'More work for Mat', 0)
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28115: policy with check option violation
```